# How to resolve schematool not found error in hive while installing on windows 10

Tags: unix, hadoop, hive

How to resolve schematool not found error in hive while installing on windows 10

```
 schematool -dbType derby -initSchema
-bash: schematool: command not found
```

Solution to resolve this

Comment: This is a bash error. What do you mean "on windows 10"?

Answer (score 0):

The error is saying that you didn't edit your PATH to include Hive's bin folder, where that script exists.

If you installed Hive actually on Windows, you need to use Windows Terminal ( CMD or Powershell), not WSL2 Bash shell

Comment: Path has been set properly in the environmental variables and used Cygwin for an execution

Comment: 1) Cygwin is no longer recommended, as you should be able to use WSL2 Bash environment. 2) Edit your question to show your bashrc file 3) Use the absolute path to the script, intead

Comment: Let me try to use WSL2 bash environment.